# How to get the Artwork of the current track in iTunes using Swift/ScriptingBridge?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, applescript, scripting-bridge

I'm currently trying my hardest but can't get anywhere. I can get the current track using `iTunes.currentTrack` but the `.artworks()` SBElementArray doesn't really get me anywhere since I don't know what to do with it. There is also `@objc public protocol iTunesArtwork: iTunesItem {` but I don't know how to get there either.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035350/get-itunes-artwork-for-current-song-with-scriptingbridge

Answer (score 0):

You can get the raw data out of one of the items and make an NSImage out of it. This is Objective-C, but it should directly translate over.

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[[[currentTrack artworks] firstObject] rawData]];
```